# IIF multi row evaluation

Tags: asp.net, sql, rdlc

Is there a way to "checkmark" multiple rows in a table in an RDLC? Each of the below IIF statements is in a different row. if paytype is hourly, and time and half, and double, I would want the table to "x" the three rows HOURLY, TIME AND HALF, and DOUBLE.

```
IIF(Fields!payType = "New", "X", " ")
IIF(Fields!payType = "Time and Half", "X", " ")
IIF(Fields!payType = "Double", "X", " ")
```

Comment: `Fields!payType` cannot be "Time and Half" and "Double" at the same time, therefore you cannot get three "x"s with the code you show.

Comment: the dataset returns the different paytypes an employee records from the database so Fields!payType CAN be "Time and Half" and "Double" in this dataset. If the employee works time and a half a record is created in the database indicating such, if an employee works the maximum number of hours allowed for time and a half and starts working double time a record is created in the database indicating such. Therefore an employee may work straight time, or time and a half (creating two records) or double time (creating three records)

Comment: Sorry, but the issue you're facing is unclear. If this involves Reporting Services report files, then add a tag for RDLC. I'm guessing that rather than having one column "Pay Type" you want three columns of "Hourly", "Time and Half", and "Double" per row displayed on your ASP.NET web page; furthermore, for a given row on the web page, you want an "X" to appear under exactly one of these columns (the others showing blanks). Is this right?

Comment: extremely sorry. tried to word it as best as i could. This is using Visual Studio, the data comes from an xsd file. I rebuilt the tablix so all rows were in the same group but now it duplicates. the first cell of each row is basically a label "Hourly", "Time and Half", and "Double". the second cell simply holds an "X" where the evaluations are true.